# Sequence of Partial Sums is Bounded and Monotone

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove that following:

Let $ \{ b_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a positive, decreasing sequence and let $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} b_k$. Prove that $\{s_{2n} \}$ is monotone and bounded.

I understand the problem intuitively, but my proof-writing has historically been a little weak. My attempt:

Since $b_n$ is decreasing, it follows that for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$b_{2n+1} > b_{2n+2} \iff 0 < b_{2n+1} - b_{2n+2}$$

Adding the quantity $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1} b_k$ to both sides, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1} b_k &< \bigg[ \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1} b_k  \bigg] + b_{2n+1} - b_{2n+2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2n+2} (-1)^{k-1} b_k \\
\end{align*}
Or equivalently,

$$s_{2n} < s_{2n+2} $$

Thus, $s_{2n}$ is monotonically increasing. Now, we claim that $s_{2n}$ is bounded above by $b_1$. Again, since $b_n$ is decreasing, we conclude that for any $n$, 
\begin{align*}
s_{2n} &= b_1 - b_2 + b_3 - \dots -b_{2n-2} + b_{2n-1} - b_{2n} \\
&< b_1 - b_3 + b_3 - \dots -b_{2n-1} + b_{2n-1} - b_{2n} \\
&= b_1 - b_{2n} \\
&< b_1
\end{align*}
Note that the final step follows from the fact that $b_1 = max\{b_n\}$. Further,
\begin{align*}
s_{2n} &= b_1 - b_2 + b_3 - b_4 \dots + b_{2n-1} - b_{2n} \\
&> 0 + 0 + \dots + 0 \\
&= 0 \\
\end{align*}
so $s_{2n}$ is bounded below by $0$. Thus, $s_{2n}$ is monotone and bounded.

Is this proof thorough enough?

Comment: Checking your title, what is a "sequence of an alternating series?" I think your work is good though.